# SwiftUI Picker greyed out in a List

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Does anyone have a fix for this? I have a `Picker` in my `List` that doesn't respond to any user input and is greyed out, but if I move it out of the `List` and into a `VStack` it functions normally.

The majority of answers I've found to this question all say that the `Picker` needs to be in a `Form` to work (which I don't understand since it works fine in a `VStack`), or that its a bug in which it only works on a physical device, which I've also tested on and gotten the same result.

I'll provide a screenshot as well as the code I'm using below

[image: Picker in simulator]

```
import SwiftUI
struct SettingsView: View {
    
@Binding var age : Int

var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                List{  
                        Picker("Your age", selection: $age) {
                                ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { number in
                                    Text("\(number)")
                                           }
                                }
                    }
        }
}
```

Comment: Picker in Form/List requires NavigationView to work, so wrap it NavigationView or change its style to wheel.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly, the wheel picker was actually more of what I wanted it to look like!

Answer (score 2):

You must embed your `List` inside a `NavigationView`, so you can actually "navigate" from *"Your age"* to the list of `Int`s.

Just add one additional layer, as shown below:

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            NavigationView {   // This is needed to navigate to the ForEach
                List {
                    Picker("Your age", selection: $age) {
                        ForEach(1..<101) { number in
                            Text("\(number)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind I fixed your ForEach range syntax

Comment: @malhal: Sure, no problem. That part I just copied from the question, I didn't check it. Good thing you caught it.